# python peewee dynamically or clauses

Tags: python, peewee

I want to dynamically `OR` multiple clauses when performing a query. I see in the peewee documentation that:

```
import operator
or_clauses = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)  # OR together all clauses
```

However, this note is somewhat unclear. What exactly is `clauses` supposed to be set to? Does anyone have any example code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

clauses would be a list of expressions in the example, sorry that it is unclear.

You might write something like:

```
clauses = [
    (User.username == 'something'),
    (User.something == 'another thing'),
    ...
]
User.select().where(reduce(operator.or_, clauses))
```

Comment: Useful example, would be nice to have this in the documentation, unless I missed it. Thank you.